# What's the syntax to partially specialize a parmeter pack argument for void type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization

I can't find a way to get this to work. Is it even possible? I don't see why it wouldn't be.

```
template <auto id, typename FirstField, typename... OtherFields>
struct FieldTypeById {
    using Type = int;
};

template <auto id>
struct FieldTypeById<id, void> {
    using Type = void;
};


int main()
{
   using t1 = FieldTypeById<0, int>::Type;
   using t2 = FieldTypeById<1>::Type;

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/AggnDq

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem in your example isn't the specialization, it's fine. The problem is that `FieldTypeById<1>` cannot deduce the type `FirstField` is. You can amend that by simply adding a default to the primary template:

```
template <auto id, typename FirstField = void, typename... OtherFields>
struct FieldTypeById {
    using Type = int;
};
```

Now all arguments are given explicitly, taken from defaults, or deduced (as an empty pack). After all the arguments are known, the specialization for those arguments can be used.

**[See it live](https://godbolt.org/z/cofRkJ)**

Comment: Hmmm. If the "main" template has `FirstField = void`, meaning that it can be directly matched with `FieldTypeById<1>`, is the specialization ever going to be instantiated? I can now see that I can achieve the same goal using just one template with `= void` and `std::conditional` inside it, but still, I wonder if it can be done via a specialization.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - The specialization is instantiated when the arguments to the template match it. But default arguments can only appear on the primary template, because that's where the pattern matching starts (to explain it colloquially).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in order to specialize a template, one must first make sure that the desired specialized instantiation can be matched to the primary template?

Comment: @StoryTeller : is that due to fact that when we pass argument list in the template there is no type deduction (unlike function template) ? I thought about that !!

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - Exactly. A specialization is applicable to a specific set of arguments to the primary template, so it needs to match against it.

Comment: Thank you, that's an important thing to learn that I somehow missed during my many years of using C++!

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd - There is a *little* deduction (for instance, the pack). But in general, you are correct. Naming a specialization doesn't involve deduction.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thx :)